# Kotlin inflate generic viewbinding class in parent

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, android-viewbinding

Aim is to declare a base class

```
abstract class BaseDialog<T : ViewBinding> : AppCompatDialogFragment() {
       lateinit var binding: T
}
```

and all child classes should extend this parent class

```
class ChildClass: BaseDialog<ChildClassViewBinding>() {
}
```

Then I want to inflate the binding in parent class and save it to binding property
This seems out of my scope of knowledge of kotlin

Is this really possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were to do this, I'd do it like this:

```
class BaseDialogFragment<T: ViewBinding>(private val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup?, Boolean) -> T)
: AppCompatDialogFragment() {
    var _binding: T? = null
    val binding: T get() = _binding ?: error("Must only access binding while fragment is attached.")

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = bindingInflater(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

with usage like:

```
class ChildClass: BaseDialog(ChildClassViewBinding::inflate) {

}
```

---

**However**, I would not do this in the first place (since there's a nice alternative). It can become messy pretty quickly to rely on inheritance for these kinds of things. What happens if you want to add some other features for a dependency injection framework, or some other common things you like to use? What if there's some features you like to use in some of your fragments but not all of them? And are you also creating base classes like this for Activity and non-Dialog Fragments?

These problems are why there's a programming axiom: "composition over inheritance".

Sometimes there's no choice but to use inheritance to avoid code duplication. But in the case of Fragments and Bindings, I don't think so. You can pass your layout reference to the super constructor, and use `ViewBinding.bind()` instead of `inflate()`. Since bindings rarely need to be accessed outside the `onViewCreated` function, you usually don't need a property for it.

```
class ChildClass: AppCompatDialogFragment(R.layout.child_class_view) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, bundle: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, bundle)
        val binding = ChildClassViewBinding.bind(view)
        //...
    }

}
```

If you do need a property for it, @EpicPandaForce has a library that makes it a one-liner and handles the leak-avoidance on destroy for you inside a property delegate.

[Library here](https://github.com/Zhuinden/fragmentviewbindingdelegate-kt)

Usage:

```
class ChildClass: AppCompatDialogFragment(R.layout.child_class_view) {
    private val binding by viewBinding(ChildClassViewBinding::bind)

}
```

Comment: Cant use the library in AppCompatDialogFragment

Comment: https://github.com/Zhuinden/fragmentviewbindingdelegate-kt/issues/15

Comment: I’m AFK, but I thought I checked when I wrote this and AppCompatDialogFragment does have the necessary constructor. That issue is about a different class which unfortunately doesn’t.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong https://github.com/Zhuinden/fragmentviewbindingdelegate-kt/issues/16

Comment: The constructor you need is there: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDialogFragment#AppCompatDialogFragment(int)

Answer (score 1):

Create Base Fragment

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VB : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

    private var _bi: VB? = null
    protected val bi: VB get() = _bi!!

    abstract val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup?, Boolean) -> VB

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        _bi = bindingInflater(inflater, container, false)
        return _bi!!.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _bi = null
    }
}
```

In your Child Fragment

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<HomeFragmentBinding>() {
    override val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup?, Boolean) -> HomeFragmentBinding
        get() = HomeFragmentBinding::inflate
}
```

Comment: May I know the purpose behind two properties bi amd _bi and why not just one?

Comment: I assume because we cant nullify a val binding

Comment: The android documentation on view binding explains why you should use two properties for binding in a Fragment. It's so you can set it to null in onDestroy to avoid leaking the views. It's possibly overkill, because in practice, views will only be leaked for a couple of seconds at most.